# Delegate function to class instance attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to fully delegate some functions from object to it's attribute without having to repeat arguments in defenition and function's docstring.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

    # I want to replace func below with something more beautiful.
    def b_func(self, arg):
        """Here I copied doc from class B."""
        return self.b.b_func(arg)

class B:
    def b_func(self, arg):
        """Some doc."""
        print('ok', arg)

# I use b_func directly from A class
a = A()
a.b_func('test')

# May be we can also get b_func with it's doc here?
help(A)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Just do clarify, you are asking how to call `help()` on `b_func()` of class `B`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: Tim Castelijns, I want to replace definition of b_func in class A (to remove repeating arguments in A.b_func and B.b_func), but I also want help(A) shows b_func as class A member (like it happens in question's code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheriting `B` can be a solution!

```
import types

class B:
    def b_func(self, arg):
        """Some doc."""
        print('ok', arg)

class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.b_func('test')

help(A)
```

The output is

```
('ok', 'test')
Help on class A in module __main__:

class A(B)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from B:
 |  
 |  b_func(self, arg)
 |      Some doc.
```

Comment: Nitpick: you're *inheriting* from `B`, not overriding it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr` method that returns reference to class instance attribute specified by
name like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_func = getattr(B(), 'b_func')

class B:
    def b_func(self, arg):
        """Some doc."""
        print('ok', arg)

# I use b_func directly from A class
a = A()
a.b_func('test')
print a.b_func.__doc__
```

Output`'Some doc.'`

Comment: You don't need `getattr` to do this. `self.b_func = B().b_func` works just fine. Also I'm not sure this is quite the solution the asker is looking for, since `help(A)` (and `pydoc` and so on) won't pick up `A.b_func`, even though you can still access the docstring manually if you know it's there, like you show.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution :

```
class B:
    def b_func(self, arg):
        """Some doc."""
        print('ok', arg)
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()
        self.b_func = b.b_func
    b_func = B.b_func
```

You get the requirements :

```
a.b_func('test') => ok test
help(A) => correct reference for b_func
```

And there is an actual delegation to an attribute. More, in idle you have the autocompletion for `a.b_func(arg)`.